# SQL outer join: use "OR" in the outer join

Tags: sql

I have a query that I use `OR` in the `outer join` and it doesn't seem it is good or right to use `OR`.  Is there a better way?

```
SELECT xxxxxx
FROM    (SELECT y.fieldA, y.fieldB  FROM y) T1 
  OUTER JOIN 
        (SELECT x.fieldA, y.fieldB FROM x) T2 
  ON T1.fieldA = T2.fieldA OR T1.fieldB = T2.fieldB
```

Comment: You should enclose the condition in brackets __ON (T1.fieldA = T2.fieldA OR T1.fieldB = T2.fieldB)__

Comment: `it doesn't seem it is good or right to use OR` What do you mean?

Comment: A join's `ON` condition just needs to be _some kind of boolean_ condition which when true between the two tables, results in a row match. An `OR` is perfectly fine there if it correctly specifies the joining condition.

Comment: Did you mean to reference `y.fieldB` in expression T2? It looks like a cut-and-paste error.

Comment: Yes I have a typo here:  It should be x.fieldB, not y.fieldB          (SELECT x.fieldA, x.fieldB FROM x) T2 
  ON T1.fieldA = T2.fieldA OR T1.fieldB = T2.fieldB  I read an article before saying using "OR" is confusing.  So using "OR" is okay as long as I use brackets like A.D. said?

Comment: @A.D.: there is no need (or requirement) to enclose the join condition in parentheses (and it will certainly not change anything here)

Comment: @angelcake: unrelated, but: using a derived table `(SELECT y.fieldA, y.fieldB  FROM y) T1` doesn't improve performance in *any* way if that is what you are thinking. It only makes the query harder to read, that's all.

Comment: if not using derived table, is there any more efficient way?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with OR, as long as it gives you the correct result!

Comment: Thank you all.  I get the correct result from using "or".